# Where is the c++ documentation for geometry_msgs in hydro?

Tags: c++, ros-hydro, geometry-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the c++ docs for geometry_msgs in diamondback: http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/geometry_msgs/html/index.html.

When I replace "diamondback" in the URL with "hydro", it's a stub: http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/geometry_msgs/html/index.html

After lots of searching, I can't seem to find the hydro docs in any other location.

**Do the docs I'm looking for exist? If so, where?**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208204/where-is-the-c++-documentation-for-geometry_msgs-in-hydro?/) by [dinosaur](https://answers.ros.org/users/21732/dinosaur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 233 on 2015-04-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rosdoc_lite` is not able to document generated code in `catkin` packages. So the API documentation of the generated message code you are looking for does not exist afaik.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2015-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0